# Assign object by reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two viewState properties.

One is a `List<MyObject> MyObjects`
And another one is `MyObject SelectedObject`

Whenever user selects an object from the list, I assign it to SelectedObject like this:

```
SelectedObject = MyObjects.Where(x=>x.MyId ==IdSelectedInUI)
```

This allows me easy manipulation of the `SelectedObject`.
Now, When I change `SelectedObject`'s properties, how Can I assign those properties back to the original object in the list? I was thinking to use `ref`, but cannot quite figure it out.

**Edit** 
All of the objects are classes, not structs.
So, here's what I have:

```
//Children are of type =List<MyParentObject.ChildObject>
 public MyParentObject MyParent
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["MyParent"] == null)
                {
                    MyParent= GetItemsFromDatabase();
                }
                return (TaskInfo)ViewState["MyParent"];
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["MyParent"] = value;
            }
        }

        public MyParentObject.ChildObject SelectedChild
        {
            get
            {
                return (MyParentObject.ChildObject)ViewState["Child"];
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["Child"] = value;
            }
        }  
        protected onButtonClick()
        {
          SelectedChild =  MyParent.Children.Where(x=>x.Child_Id == Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
         SelectedChild.Property2 = "test2" //OldValue "test1"
         //now if I run 
        MyParent.Children.Where(x=>x.Child_Id ==Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text)).Select(x=>x.Property2) //Shows "test1" and I expect "test2"
        }
        }
```

Comment: `SelectedObject` is not of type `MyObject` but `IEnumerable<MyObject>`. How do you change it's properties?

Answer (score 2):

`SelectedObject` is an object reference. It is identical with the original object in the list - `SelectedObject` and the "original" object are the same object. If you are seeing behavior that indicates otherwise, please update your question.

Comment: I think the issue here is that the object is being assigned into ViewState, then when it comes back, the ViewState is restored with a new instance.

Comment: The OP also mentions `ViewState`. `MyObjects` might be a computed property that serialises to / deserialises from VS.

Comment: I am assuming the user is coming from a c++ background. I was extremely confused about values and references when I made the transition to c#.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  Assuming MyObject is a class, it is passed "by value", but the value being passed is a reference to the original object.

For instance:

```
void Mutate(SomeObject x)
{
     x.val = "banana";
}
void Reassign(SomeObject x)
{
     x = new SomeObject();
     x.val = "Garbage";
}
public static void Main()
{
     SomeObject x = new SomeObject();
     x.val = "Apple";
     Console.WriteLine(x.val); // Prints Apple
     Mutate(x);
     Console.WriteLine(x.val); // Prints banana
     Reassign(x);
     Console.WriteLine(x.val); // Still prints banana
}
```

This is how passing objects works in C#.  You can modify the contents, but not the "value" of the object itself (which is a pointer to it in memory).

If you are looking to change the contents of the object, nothing special needs to be done.

Passing an object by ref parameter will allow you to reassign the reference to it.  For example, if:

```
void Reassign(ref SomeObject x) // implementation
```

Was used in the previous example, the print out of the final WriteLine would have been "Garbage", as the reference itself was changed, and due to the ref parameter, this changed the reference in the caller as well.

+Edit
If MyObject is a struct, however, the structure is copied when passed, and reassigning it inside a different scope will have no effect on the original structure.

What you could do for this is to have a function return the structure and assign it:

```
MyStruct Mutate(MyStruct x){}
// calling
myStruct = Mutate(myStruct);
```

Or do it by reference parameter.